# Reverse if statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I understand how an if condition works. Like this:

```
if (condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is true
}
```

But how do I reverse e.g. do not fire this line of code if statement is correct?

```
if $("span:contains('399')) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```

Comment: javascript 101 ... `if (!condition) { ... }`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!condition) {
    block of code to be executed if the condition is false
}
```